# How to use Haskell generics to populate a record?

Tags: haskell, generics

Let's say I have a data structure like the following:

```
[("a", "123"), ("b", "234")]
```

and I want to populate a record like this:

```
data R = R { a :: Int, b :: String }
```

so that I end up with a record `r { a = 123, b = "234" }` without having to manually write conversion code.

Various packages (like aeson and some of the command line parsing packages) do something like this and I'd like to know about the available mechanisms that let me do this and how they are used. I've heard about `Data.Data`, `Data.Typeable` and a few others but don't know how these work to make the magic happen.

Comment: I know `aeson` does it with `GHC.Generics`. Have you tried reading the `aeson` source code? Reading source on Hackage is often a good way to learn. Generics can be a bit weird, and there are some things they just don't do well, but I think they'll probably work for your present purpose.

Comment: Oh, and you should read the documentation for `GHC.Generics` in the module and in the user's guide. But that documentation is not exactly the best ever, so you probably want to combine it with example code to get a sense of what it's talking about.

Comment: Yeah, the instant generics paper does a better job explaining things.

Answer (score 1):

[The GHC.Generics docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) have a straightforward tutorial which can get you 99% of the way there. Here's some code based on that tutorial:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.List (lookup)
import Data.Proxy

class FromKV' f where
    fromKV' :: [(String, String)] -> f p

instance FromKV' V1 where
    fromKV' _ = error "fromKV' V1"

instance FromKV' U1 where
    fromKV' _ = U1

instance (FromKV c) => FromKV' (K1 i c) where
    fromKV' = K1 . fromKV

-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/24474958/477476
data SelectorProxy s (f :: * -> *) a = SelectorProxy
type SelectorProxyFor s = SelectorProxy s Proxy ()

instance (Read a, Selector s) => FromKV' (M1 S s (Rec0 a)) where
    fromKV' = M1 . K1 . maybe (error $ unwords ["fromKV' : missing key:", key]) read . lookup key
      where
        key = selName (SelectorProxy :: SelectorProxyFor s)

instance (FromKV' f) => FromKV' (D1 t f) where
    fromKV' = M1 . fromKV'

instance (FromKV' f) => FromKV' (C1 t f) where
    fromKV' = M1 . fromKV'

instance (FromKV' f, FromKV' g) => FromKV' (f :*: g) where
    fromKV' kvs = fromKV' kvs :*: fromKV' kvs

class FromKV a where
    fromKV :: [(String, String)] -> a
    default fromKV :: (Generic a, FromKV' (Rep a)) => [(String, String)] -> a
    fromKV = to . fromKV'

data MyR = MyR{ a :: Int, b :: String }
         deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromKV MyR
```

The missing 1% (but that is somewhat orthogonal to your question anyway) is changing the `FromKV' (M1 S s (Rec0 a)` instance so that `String`s are consumed verbatim instead of `read`ing them: with the above code, this works:

```
*Main> fromKV [("a", "123"), ("b", "\"234\"")] :: MyR
MyR {a = 123, b = "234"}
```

but this doesn't:

```
*Main> fromKV [("a", "123"), ("b", "234")] :: MyR
MyR {a = 123, b = "*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```