# List constructor names using generics in haskell

Tags: haskell

I know how to list constructor names in the following way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}

module Generics where     

import           Data.Proxy          
import           GHC.Generics        

class Names' f where
  names' :: Proxy f -> [String]
instance (Names' f) => Names' (M1 D t f) where
  names' _ = names' (Proxy :: Proxy f)
instance (Names' f, Names' g) => Names' (f :+: g) where
  names' _ = (names' (Proxy :: Proxy f) ++ (names' (Proxy :: Proxy g)))
instance (Constructor c) => Names' (C1 c f) where
  names' _ = [conName (undefined :: C1 c f g)]

data Test = Foo | Bar Int | Baz { x :: Int } deriving (Generic)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ names' (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep Test))
--> ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
```

But in that case we need a `Proxy (Rep Test)`. How to do same thing with a given `Proxy Test`?

I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24474958/1722399) how to get first selector of the record, but can't figure out how to solve my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleContexts #-}
names :: forall t. (Generic t, Names' (Rep t)) => Proxy t -> [String]
names _ = names' (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep t))
```

Which works because `Proxy`s are immaterial: as long as you can name the type you can build a `Proxy` for it. (Side note: Unless you are using GHC <8, you should probably use the `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` extensions over `Proxy`. On GHC >=8, the only time you ever need `Proxy`-like things is in higher-rank contexts.)

You may also say

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
class (Generic t, Names' (Rep t)) => Names t where
  names :: Proxy t -> [String]
instance (Generic t, Names' (Rep t)) => Names t where
  names _ = names' (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep t))
```

To get a nice constraint synonym `Names t` for `(Generic t, Names' (Rep t))`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to "extract" a `Proxy` within the function declaration? Such as

    `names_ :: (Generic t, Names' (Rep t)) => Maybe t -> [String]` Or I have to pass the value or `Proxy`? Currently GHC complains that can't deduce type when I write something like `names (Proxy :: Proxy t)`

Comment: You already have `ScopedTypeVariables` on (or else `Names'` wouldn't compile). This is what lets me make a `Proxy` out of a type variable. However, you need to use a `forall` like `forall t. (Generic t, Names' (Rep t)) => Proxy t -> [String]` to actually get `t` in scope. Otherwise, `t` is not in scope, and GHC thinks `Proxy :: Proxy t` means `Proxy :: forall t. Proxy t`, which has no free type variables.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Data.Data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html).

```
{-# language DerivingDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable
data Test = ... deriving (Data, Typeable)
```

Now you can use `dataTypeOf` to get a value of type `DataType` representing your ADT (E.g. `dataTypeOf (undefined :: Test)`).

Then `dataTypeConstrs` will give you a list of `Constr` (constructors).

Then `showConstr` on each to print the name.